# Circular Loading Bar

Tags: jquery, html

I am using this jQuery plugin called Simple Circular Loading Bar with Percentage - Rotator http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/Simple-jQuery-Circular-Loading-Bar-with-Percentage-Rotator.html

how can I add more div

Here is a jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/fegvc5h8/

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#rotator").rotator({
    starting: 0,
    ending: 100,
    percentage: true,
    color: 'green',
    lineWidth: 7,
    timer: 10,
    radius: 40,
    fontStyle: 'Calibri',
    fontSize: '20pt',
    fontColor: 'darkblue',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    callback: function() {}
  });
});
```

and here is the code

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "how can I add more div".  Could you explain a little more what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What do you want to add, more loading bars? Or on click to fill the loading bar by percentage...

Comment: I need more loading bars. 'I need more rounds.
Example 
 <div id="rotator" style="height:100px;width:100px"></div>
<div id="rotator" style="height:100px;width:100px"></div>
<div id="rotator" style="height:100px;width:100px"></div>
<div id="rotator" style="height:100px;width:100px"></div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible .
http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/en83d3uu/

Open `rotator.js` file of this script and change the code as below.There were dublicate canvas ids which i fixed by adding "-random number" to the canvas element id with jquery `Math.random():`

```
...
var n = Math.random();
this.empty().append("<canvas height ="+this.height() + " width="+this.width()+" id='my-canvas-"+n+"'/ ></canvas>");
var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas-'+n);
```

And you can add as many as you want by adding div elements with different ids to your html:

```
<div id="rotator" style="height:300px;width:300px"></div>
<div id="rotator2" style="height:300px;width:300px"></div>
```

Comment: exactly what I was working on... only thing is I adding a count variable and incremented it instead of random number... my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fegvc5h8/20/

Comment: @Karthik Ganesan that happens :) . I also upvoted your comment though.I 'll stay with the random solution for this case.thanks